# Sci-fi manga about a boy with an alien girl classmate

Tags: story-identification, aliens, manga

Two to three years ago, I was reading a very interesting sci-fi manga, but I dropped it and now I can't remember the name. It was not new when I read it, but I'm pretty sure it was released after 2000.

If I am right the protagonist was at middle school. He was an average boy and there were this alien girl as his classmate. The alien girl lived in a abandoned tram, had a black bob cut with bangs, and looked completely normal (although two other aliens were big and detailed).

At some point the girl got in a fight with an other alien at the Ferris wheel and the boy got pierced through heart and then the girl saved him somehow. (It was a bloody mess). Then there was some drama in school at some point and then there was the boy's twin brother, who had long hair, and his alien female friend. I dropped it at this point because I did not like the twin brothers hairstyle.

The art was rather beautiful (in my eyes). It was probably an English version, but I have been reading manga in five different languages for years, so I can't be sure.

It was actually kind of a confusing book. The themes were something like: being lonely, getting friends, and other stuff that could found from *[Shugo Chara!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shugo_Chara!)*, but instead of handling fights in a way *[Shugo Chara!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shugo_Chara!)* does (so it would be good for younger audience), it handled it like *[Akumetsu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akumetsu)* did except there was no guns.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! You've provided some potentially useful data above; check [this post] for suggestions on other bits of data that may jog your memory about this item. Do you remember when you read this? if you were reading the story from the start? Did the story shift from being about the first boy and alien girl to the twin brother and (another?) alien girl when you stopped reading? Any idea how much you read? Any specific description of physical differences with aliens (cat eyes, tails, etc.)?

Comment: Mursuke> Do you have a picture?

Comment: I did read it about 3-2 years ago, but I did not start reading it when it was first published. It was made after 2000, but I am not exatly sure about the year. It did not shift the protagonist, but the brother started became the antagonist. I did read about 20-30 chapters. I don’t think there were anything special at the girl at least nothing that could make her completly unregonizable. Btw. The girl had black bob cut with bangs. Other aliens that were shown besides those two girls were big & detailed those kind you see in R-18 scifi games. I sadly do not have a picture.

Comment: Hitoribocchi no Chikyuu Shinryaku

Answer (score 4):

[*Hitoribocchi no Chikyuu Shinryaku*](https://myanimelist.net/manga/35551/Hitoribocchi_no_Chikyuu_Shinryaku) (2012).

Kouichi is a high school student who lives with his grandfather and helps him with his coffee shop, he has a twin brother who's sick and stays at the hospital. At the entrance ceremony, he meets a strange girl wearing a mask, she claims that 10 years ago she came to Earth and saved his life by giving him a heart, which she tries to reclaim; but the heart completely assimilated with the boy. She offers to be friends and take over the planet. Of course, the boy refuses and leaves to help his grandfather at the coffee shop, but is soon attacked by another alien. The strange girl shows up again, and says that she will help if he will become her friend and help her take over the world.

Later in the story we find out that she lives in abandoned tramway. The Earth is an isolated planet, and only the keys that are on Earth will help to access the full invasion. Only special individuals can go to Earth because it's "locked". So the girl and the boy defend the planet from other aliens while also searching for the keys.

I don't want to spoil the story anymore because the story is amazing one of the best sci-fi I ever read and the art style is amazing shame that it is not so popular.

---

I got here searching for this specific manga; Google search is pretty useless because it searches what is popular and based on cookies, so to find it what I did was specify manga website and then search by description. Only then did it give normal results.

Comment: Thanks for explaining _how_ you got there, but you'll have to also explain _why_ it fits. How does it match the OP's criteria? Check out [How to write a good story-ID answer?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/21267) for pointers on how to expand what seems to be a good answer.

Comment: Sorry I was looking for the same manga I read long time ago, so I stumbled to this forum (witch I don't know anything about), it has word for word the same detailed events in the manga, but there were no correct answers in this page. So when I finally found the manga I decided to share it (and let my frustration a little bit, because it was 4 in the morning). So I didn't know any rules, just wanted to help a guy. I will try to eddit.

Answer (score 1):

Middle school boy meets an alien girl class mate with sci-fi elements?

Kinda broad, considering the genre and various little-known mangas that fall into it... they all fit underneath the bigger umbrella of "supernatural girlfriend"... but given your detail, one that comes to my mind most strongly would be **The World of Narue** (2003):

[image: World of Narue cover, five young characters in school uniforms, in the sky, front character is a girl with long brown hair]

From [Anime News Network](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=2128):

> **Genres:** comedy, drama, romance, science fiction
>
> **Themes:** aliens
>
> **Plot Summary:** Iizuka Kazuto is a 14 year old boy who meets a somewhat weird but cute and charming girl named Narue Nanase who claims she is an Alien. The show is about the trials and tribulations of the young couple as they get to know each other.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_of_Narue):

> Kazuto Izuka is an average 14-year-old boy who one day encounters an abandoned puppy that turns into a space alien creature but is saved by schoolmate named Narue Nanase. When he goes to thank her, he discovers she too is a space alien whose father was part of a galactic exploration team. With the encouragement of his friend, Masaki Maruo, Izuka asks Narue out on a date. Narue is reluctant at first, but after Kazuto confesses his love to her, and assures her that he is not bothered by her alien heritage, Narue agrees and they start dating.

To be honest, the series has more comedy/slice of life/romance leanings, but there are some pretty sci-fi heavy aspects, especially when it comes to the tech:

[image: young girl in Japanese school uniforms, in the middle of several airships, a planet can be seen in the background]

Narue *herself* though seems to be pretty much terrestrial *human,* with no notable aspects that differentiate her from other Earthlings; she has no noticeable deformities, no identifying marks, no genetic distinctions, no psychic powers, no enhanced abilities, no physical mutations... considering she was basically raised on Earth, the girl doesn't even have any real "quirky" behavior that  makes her seriously seem like a "Fish out of water". She's more or less your average middle-schooler, just kind of... nominally odd. So the "alien" aspect isn't quite as apparent as in other series.

Answer (score -2):

[*Busou Renkin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buso_Renkin) (2003)

> The narrative of Buso Renkin follows Kazuki Muto, who saves Tokiko Tsumura and is killed by an alchemical monster known as a homunculus. Tokiko, an alchemist warrior, feels responsible and revives him by replacing his destroyed heart with a kakugane (核鉄). The kakugane is an alchemical device which, when activated, takes a weapon form based on its user's personality, forming a buso renkin—the only thing that can destroy a homunculus. Kazuki creates his own buso renkin and joins Tokiko in the fight against the homunculi and their master, Koushaku Chouno. Chouno, who has renamed himself "Papillon", is killed by Kazuki, but is later resurrected by the L.X.E., a humanoid homunculi group led by Chouno's great-great-grandfather Bakushaku Chouno, now calling himself Dr. Butterfly. In various battles, Kazuki, Tokiko and Captain Bravo (their team leader) destroy most of the L.X.E.'s members. After learning that Dr. Butterfly believes him to be weak and useless, Papillon rebels against the L.X.E. and kills Dr. Butterfly.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! I've taken the liberty of editing in some basic information. However, I don't know enough of this to be able to match it properly, could you [edit] to clarify how this matches the OP's description?

Comment: Why did you rollback TheLethalCarrot's edits? You're just going to attract more downvotes and delete votes unless you take his advice and explain *why* you believe this is the manga OP is looking for.